# AndEngine - handling touches multiple sprites in a single area

Tags: java, android, andengine

This is for a game I'm building where sprites are constantly overlapping since their spawn locations are randomly generated. The player must tap some sprite at a certain time. The problem arrives if the they need to tap the bottom sprite of 2 or more overlapping sprites. The touch is only registered for one of the sprites which makes the game impossible sometimes.

Is it possible to get an array of all sprites in the touch location?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out. I just had to set the return value of onAreaTouched to false.

As soon as a sprite's onAreaTouched returns true, the touch event ends.